# Android:: qemu-system-i386.exe . Permission Denied

Tags: android

I created a small ActivityFile.java. After running it, it takes a while to show the Android Emulator on screen. After 10 minutes, I got this error.

```
Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: Unable to open 
C:\Android\.android\avd\MyNexus5API25.avd\data\misc\pstore\pstore.bin: Permission denied
```

I am a beginner to Android Studio, so do not the reason behind this issue.

Please help??

Comment: This file is also modified when saving state of the virtual machine on closing. If it fails, the machine would not start from saved state. If that's the situation you find yourself in, for time being choose Boot Option: "Cold Boot" in advanced settings of this virtual machine in AVD Manager.

Answer (score 24):

Go to `C:\Android.android\avd\MyNexus5API25.avd\data\misc`, make right click on `pstore`, pick `Properties` and uncheck box `Only for reading` (Title may be a little different). This is a new non critical bug (about 2 days ago update), you should not attach importance to this.

Comment: I am a beginner in Android development.I created a simple app with one page only.When I run my App, the emulator gets launched but my app is not listed in the Home launcher.  What might be the problem??  In addition to this,when emulator gets launched, it takes too much for a device to come online showing message as "Waiting for the target device to come online".  Please help me in resolving these issues also.

Comment: 1) Some versions of Android have menu of applications, check this. 2) Android Studio can't  install app on not ready device. Android emulator must turn on the device. If it is too long you should reinstall Android components on SSD, check RAM usage and make sure that the processor is powerful enough OR try debug on real device, it is usually already on.

Comment: I'm getting the error message in question upon closing the emulator. Trying this fix gets rid of the error for one shut down of the emulator. But then when I start and stop the emulator, the error shows up again and the directory is again marked as read only.

Comment: As the only bug report I found had no emulator files attached, I created a new bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/73249556. Seeing exactly the symptoms as described by @justarandomuser12345.

Answer (score 0):

just did this  delete the lock file in this route and it worked for me C:\Users*your user*.android\avd/Nexus_4_API_22.avd/*.lock

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and i solved it by recreating the AVD from scratch

- use Android studio and delete the AVD first
- delete the Folders according to your AVD name ex-: Nexus_5X_API_27
  [image: folder structure]
- create a new AVD from the Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

project--> gradle --> `xxclasspath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'`

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

you have to change one.