# Android Studio 3.0.1 virtual emulator permission denied error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

So I just installed Android Studio on my PC, and I'm just trying to do a simple test app to make sure everything is working smoothly and such.

However, whenever I try to run my app in the virtual emulator, I get an error that says "permission denied".

How do I get rid of this error?

Here's a pic of said error plus the virtual emulator:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHBId.jpg

The blacked-out spots just cover up my name.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: paste your activity code and layout file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48072173/8587358 See if this helps. It says it's just a non-critical bug.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have an administrator account on your computer?

Or maybe you should try to install the last version of the emulator in beta mode to get the last feature. For me, doing this resolved a lot of issues.