# Android Studio emulator file Permission denied

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm trying to learn android studio, but there's always the same error that pops after closing the emulator.

It says that ...\pstore.bin Permission denied.
It only causes my emulator to freeze for some time, nothing more for now.

I've noticed that it gives that error because this file is set to "Read only", but when i uncheck it manually it gets checked again after running an app in Android Studio.
Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48052940/android-qemu-system-i386-exe-permission-denied

Comment: I've read that but i don't think there's anything useful for me, as i said, unchecking "read only" doesn't work, like in the first answer, and i don't have .lock file, so i can't delete it

Comment: Here are lots of scenarios related your issues. Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554337/cannot-launch-avd-in-emulatorqt-library-not-found

Comment: @HardyAndroid, I won't downvote a comment, but the question you linked is not related to this permission issue. Sure you got the right URL?

Comment: This is fixed!! https://issuetracker.google.com/73249556.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI: I filed a bug report for this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/73249556.

An earlier report was marked "Needs Info" as the user hadn't attached any files.

As a (lousy) workaround, you can try unchecking the "read only" property on that file before shutting down the emulator, each time you run it.

Comment: Thanks for filing a issue report. I ran into the same problem.

Comment: This has been fixed! Meanwhile, it's safe to ignore the error.