# Android Studio 3.0.1 - Emulator black screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I'm using Android studio v3.0.1 and trying to use the emulator. I have created several different virtual devices but all of them fail to boot.

The IDE says 'waiting for target device to come online'.

I have reinstalled Android studio, the emulator, SDK. I have wiped each virtual device and cold booted and still the same.

I have tried the solutions presented in other similar questions on here but it appears to have a different cause.

Is there a fix?

Error message:

```
15:18   Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: Unable to open C:\Users\Sam\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_27.avd\data\misc\pstore\pstore.bin: Permission denied
```

Comment: first boot will take time , did you wait long enough?

Comment: @Redman waited 5 minutes, still black screen.

Comment: Which OS and graphics card/driver are you using? If you're on linux with an AMD card, try software rendering and/or another driver. Solved it for me.

Comment: @dedda1994 using Windows 10, integrated graphics on Laptop. I've used android studio before on here with the emulator working fine, recently seems to have stopped working.

Comment: Click in Power button in emulator. It will turn your "device" on.

Comment: @Psytho Doesn't work. It normally auto boots though.

Comment: It was normally booting in Android Studio 2. In AS 3 you have to "power on".

Comment: @Psytho I don't think so , it auto boots for me

Comment: @Redman Hmm, I have to turn it on after updating to 3. That's strange.

Comment: Is there any way to get more information about the emulator while its running to help diagnose?

Comment: sam you can always try alternative like genymotion,andy,blue stacks ets

Comment: @Redman I might have to, was just hoping to get this fixed as it was working fine for months.

Comment: Error that comes up is Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: Unable to open C:\Users\Sam\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_27_2.avd\data\misc\pstore\pstore.bin: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

Go to the path

`C:\Users\Sam\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_27_2.avd\data\misc\pstore\pstore.bin`

right click on pstore, selectProperties and uncheck box Only for reading

Source https://stackoverflow.com/a/48072173/6478047

Comment: The issue is marked as fixed by google ,it should not happen https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73249556

Comment: The property appears to be getting rechecked after running the emulator. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @SamD That is a bug and google said ,they fixed it , make sure your android studio and emulator are up to date

Comment: Android studio version is 3.0.1. Emulator up to date. Is there something i'm missing?