# Android studio app isn't running

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to get started with android studio, and I can't debug anything on an actual device or on a virtual device. I reinstalled android studio, but that didn't help anything.

Here's what I tried for a virtual device:

- Tools > AVD Manager > Edit > Graphics: Software
- Tools > AVD Manager > Cold Boot Now
- Adding a new virtual device

Whatever I do, the emulator turns on really slowly. Here's one of the errors I got:

```
11:53 PM    Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.

11:53 PM    Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'

11:53 PM    Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed

11:53 PM    Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'

11:54 PM    Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: Unable to open C:\Users\simch\.android\avd\Pixel_XL_API_26.avd\data\misc\pstore\pstore.bin: Permission denied

11:54 PM    ADB rejected shell command (getprop): closed
```

I then tried run the app on an actual android device, but android studio doesn't recognize it. The physical phone says it's in USB debugging mode, but when I try running the app from android studio, it doesn't show any connected devices.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48052940/android-qemu-system-i386-exe-permission-denied

Comment: @vikaskumar I tried creating a new virtual device, which didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

If you using an real phone to debugging, we should check the bellow points:

1. Check your device os version, which must install on sdk
2. Device usb debugging mood enable
3. kill the adb server and re start the adb server
4. Check the phone connection cable,[In my experienced, some cable unable to connect with usb debugging mood ]

Comment: Just did all 4 options, and they didn't fix the problem. But thanks for the answer!