# Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: Unable to open `/path/pstore.bin`: Permission denied

Tags: java, android, android-studio, emulation

Why is android emulator not starting? It was working but accidentally it starts to throw this exception and the emulator hangs up on `Start Screen` as follows 
[image: image Here] 
and in android studio, when I run my code it says

> Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: Unable to open C:\Users\Aman.android\avd\Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo.avd\data\misc\pstore\pstore.bin: Permission denied

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48052940/android-qemu-system-i386-exe-permission-denied) I unchecked  the `pstore` folder `Readonly` attribute but it didn't help me. I have also tried deleting the folder it doesn't also fix the problem.
I am woking on `windows 10` with

- Android Studio 3.3
- API Level 27
- Android 8.1 (Google APIs)

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing files on the start of the app? because if that's the case than you have to ask the runtime permission first.

Comment: the problem is that the emulator do not start at all

Comment: clear data on the emulator. Give Android studio as an administrator and qemu as administrator and i think your problem will be solved/

Comment: how should I clean the data from the emulator? Android Studio is running in Administrators permission..? Also the `pstore folder is setting it self readonly`, can it be the cause for that??

Comment: change folders permission than.